# Checking for Multigraph Isomorphism in Python iGraph

Tags: python, igraph

I'm running igraph on python and I've noticed that igraph does not implement graph isomorphism checks properly for multigraphs. As an example:

```
$ python

Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import igraph

>>> g = igraph.Graph(3)
>>> g.add_edges([(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)])

>>> h = igraph.Graph(3)
>>> h.add_edges([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 2), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)])
```

It is clear that graph g and graph h are *not* isomorphic (g contains loops and h does not). And yet igraph identifies them as isomorphic.

```
>>> g.isomorphic(h)
True
```

The same happens with isomorphic_vf2:

```
>>> g.isomorphic_vf2(h)
True
```

I need a function, *multigraph_Isomorphic(g, h)*, that will return True if and only if the multigraphs g and h are isomorphic.

I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The isomorphism algorithms built into igraph support simple graphs only (i.e. no loop or multiple edges). You can get around this limitation by using vertex and edge colors in `isomorphic_vf2`. The idea is the following:

1. First, you assign color *k* to vertices having *k* loop edges incident on them.
2. Then, if you have multiple edges, you create an edge attribute named `weight` with value equal to 1 for each edge, and then call `g.simplify(loops=False, weight="sum")` to collapse the multiple edges into simple ones and assign their original multiplicities to an edge attribute named `weight`.
3. Then you do the same thing for `h`.
4. Finally, you call `g.isomorphic(h, color1=g.vs["color"], color2=h.vs["color"], edge_color1=g.es["weight"], edge_color2=h.es["weight"])`. This would require the VF2 algorithm to match vertices and edges based not only on their connections but also on their colors.